# How to add a parent view to a child view programmatically?

Tags: android

I would like to add a `HorizontalScrollView` as a parent to the child view `LinearLayout`. Is there a way to add a parent view to a child view programmatically in `Android` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove child from original parent, add it to the new parent, then add the new parent to the original parent.

Something like:

```
// Get reference to the child view
val childView = R.findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.myChildLinearLayout)

// Create horizontal scroll view (or inflate)
val horizScrollView = HorizontalScrollView(context)

// Remove child view from original parent
removeView(child)

//TODO: setup new layout params on childView as needed

// Add child view to the horizontal scroll view
horizScrollView.addView(childView)

//TODO: setup layout params on horizontal scrollview as needed

// Add horizontal scrollview to the original parent
addView(horizScollView)
```